# Android: compileDebugKotlin FAILED with java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I've faced a strange issue when building my android project. `compileDebugKotlin` task fails with `java.lang.ClassCastException`, and it refers to some inner kotlin classes. I also cannot determine what exactly caused this issue. I have no idea how to deal with such kind of issues. The only thing that came to my mind was that there might be some condradictory gradle dependencies. But all the dependencies in app module `build.gradle` file are up-to-date and essential for my project. Please comment if you have any clue how this can be possibly solved.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtSuperTypeCallEntry cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression (org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtSuperTypeCallEntry and org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeDiagnosticSuppressor.isSuppressed(ComposeDiagnosticSuppressor.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.BindingContextSuppressCache.isSuppressedByExtension(KotlinSuppressCache.kt:241)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.KotlinSuppressCache.isSuppressed(KotlinSuppressCache.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.KotlinSuppressCache.access$isSuppressed(KotlinSuppressCache.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.KotlinSuppressCache$filter$1.invoke(KotlinSuppressCache.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.KotlinSuppressCache$filter$1.invoke(KotlinSuppressCache.kt:49)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.filter(_Collections.kt:3557)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.DiagnosticsWithSuppression.all(DiagnosticsWithSuppression.java:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.diagnostics.MutableDiagnosticsWithSuppression.all(MutableDiagnosticsWithSuppression.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport$Companion.reportDiagnostics(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport$Companion.reportDiagnostics(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:253)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:170)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:434)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:357)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:299)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:622)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1713)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My gradle dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // Compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10"
    // Material Design
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-rc01"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    // Coil for Jetpack Compose
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0"
    // Material Icons
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.5'
```

[image]

Comment: Usually with Gradle, I just comment out the dependencies/other commands and the files that use them until it starts building. If you have a git commit that already knowing to be buildable, you have very little work to do.

Comment: I just ran in to this exception after updating to Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8092744, built on January 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.6.2

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got same stacktrace when I added named parameters calling a java class. There was no IDE warning, and the stacktrace didn't point to it. Undoing the named parameter stopped giving me this error.